# node error, nodenv: couldn't find any version specified for use

Tags: node.js, installation, npm

After a succesfull installation of node I get the following;

```
$ npm
nodenv: couldn't find any version specified for use
$ node
nodenv: couldn't find any version specified for use
```

Would anybody know where this is coming from? I installed node/npm through the standard tutorials on my mac but I keep getting this error. Is there something I should have done but didn't?

#### Edit:

The previous question suggested that this error was due to boxen. This isn't the case so I've changed the question a bit to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

turns out I couldn't find the command that allows you to set the version;

you can see all the different versions through the `nodenv` command;

```
$ nodenv versions
v0.10
v0.10.13
v0.4
v0.4.10
v0.6
v0.6.20
v0.8
v0.8.8
```

you can then set the version by doing;

```
$ nodenv local v0.10
```

Comment: If `nodenv versions` prints nothing, try running `nodenv local v0.10` anyway and it may still work